# Using REGEXP in mysql search as well ignoring stopwords

Tags: mysql

I have a simple statement using REGEXP to find words in the title of articles and return those records that contain those words in them.

```
$search = 'submit|ticket|to';

SELECT * FROM xxx_kb WHERE title REGEXP '$search' LIMIT 6
```

What I would like to do is to have REGEXP ignore stopwords, in this case the word `to`. I have a table with stop words that I can compare to but I am just not sure how to ignore them in the statement with REGEXP

Comment: `REGEXP` doesn't know anything about stop words.  But full text search does; you could look into using full text search.

Comment: If you don't want to match "to" then it isn't clear why you have "to" in your regex.   Can you clarify this?  What are you actually trying to match?